# How to repair an USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I just have used my USB drive and at one day when I plug in it into a device it showed me an error. I tried all USB ports on 4 PCs.

**Here's picture of this USB drive in "This PC"**
[This USB drive in "This PC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcvEc.jpg)

**Here's picture of opened "Properties" of this USB drive in "This PC"**
[Properties in "This PC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIRzY.png)

**Here's picture of what I see when I try to check errors in "Properties" in "This PC"**
[Trying to check errors in "Properties" in "This PC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVu0G.png)

**Here's picture of what I see when I try to open this USB drive via "This PC"**
[Trying to open this USB drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ1EA.png)

**Here's picture of this USB drive in "Disk Management"**
[This USB drive in "Disk Management"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UJ80.jpg)

**Here's the picture of what I see when I click on this USB drive in "Disk Management" via right button of mouse.**
[Right mouse button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbNlY.png)

**Here's the picture of what I see when I open "Properties" of this USB drive in "Disk Management"**
["Properties" in "Disk Management"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0cos.png)

**Here's the picture of what I see when I open "Volumes" in "Properties" of this USB drive in "Disk Management"**
["Volumes" in "Properties" in "Disk Management"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrLWx.png)

PowerShell can detect this USB drive, but Command Prompt can't.

CrystalDiskMark7 can't detect this USB drive. Android devices can't detect this USB drive. AS SSD Benchmark can't detect this USB drive. All Windows PCs can detect this USB drive, but can't run it.
How to repair it?

Comment: Seems like it's dead.

Comment: Throw it away and buy a new one. They are consumable.

Comment: Make and model of usb drive?

Comment: @Moab Kingston DataTraveler G3 16 GB USB 2.0

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you can not repair or recover data from a USB flash drive if Disk Management does not show a physical capacity. It can be explained by either the controller failing to communicate with the NAND chip(s) or the firmware being corrupt. I use 'firmware' quite liberal and consider the translator part of the firmware too.

[image]

In general it requires accessing the NAND memory via NAND protocol by using specialized data recovery hardware, however there are no guarantees this will always be possible. I use these devices:

[image]

The device on the left allows for recovery from devices that are in bad shape (many read errors, disconnecting etc.) but that are still detected. Occasionally it detects devices Windows can not. It can be used with normal file recovery tools. The device on the right is my NAND reader which I use in combination with the software "Flash-Extractor". I have many adapters for most common NAND chips. The purpose of the software is to reproduce the controller algorithms for ECC error correction and XOR scrambling and such.

If the USB flash drive is a so called monolith recovery becomes even more of a hassle as we need to solder wires between these points and the NAND reader (if the pin-out is known):

[image]